# Get stores countries and Languages REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Is there is a built in rest API to get :

- Stores Countries.
- Stores Languages.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should try:

1) Store Countries.

```
 GET /V1/directory/countries
 GET /V1/directory/countries/:countryId
```

Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/CountryInformationAcquirer.php`

2) Store Language.

```
GET  /V1/store/storeConfigs
```

Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Service/StoreConfigManager.php`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but first API return all countries. I mean return the default country set in admin->stores->configurations->general. or in another meaning i want ti return the countries which stores installed in only like http://uae.souq.com/ae-ar/, http://egypt.souq.com/eg-ar/

Comment: I see, it's better when we build our own API. Tomorrow, I will take a look and try to build one.

Comment: Ah! Did you try with `GET  /V1/store/storeConfigs`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried also `GET /V1/store/storeViews`. Any update about Countries store?